# in blender game mode after scene changing all the shadows or light dissapeer

Tags: game-engine, 3d-view, lighting

When I changed back to previous scene all the color or texture has gone.

after changing scene
[image: after changing scene]

before change scene
[image: before change scene]

Comment: Make sure all the scenes have the material mode set as GLSL, maybe one is GLSL and other is Multitexture, so this might happen.